# Driving in Dubai with an International Driving Permit and temporary license

Tags: indian-citizens, dubai, driving-licenses

I have a valid Indian license and an IDP. I know that you cannot drive a private vehicle with an IDP. But I've read that you can apply for a temporary license and using this you can drive a private vehicle.

Firstly, is it possible to get a temporary license in Dubai as an Indian with a tourist visa?

Secondly, if I can get a temporary license in Dubai with the validity of my visa, do I have to appear for any kind of testing or classes before I can drive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this 2016 article](https://www.thenational.ae/business/can-dubai-tourists-drive-only-hired-cars-1.137523), there's no issue with private cars. A local license plus IDP allows you to drive any car.

Just make sure the insurance covers you. An insurance policy may have limitations regarding the driver.

Getting a license, temporary or other, where you're not a residence is normally not possible. You're expected to get a license in your home country, and then you can use it abroad.